# How to test an HTTPS request in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Stackoverflow has a number of answers for this, but they all don't work. It seems like they're outdated.
I've tried code like

```
get :index, protocol: :https
```

Answer (score 1):

What your code snippet suggests it's a spec `type: :request`. The thing is - HTTP is not really involved in those kinds of tests.

What happens is, when you type `get :index`, a request object is being made, passed to rails, and response object is captured and you test against its state
`expect(response).to be_success`

So you'd need to specify **what** exactly do you want to test:

- is your app redirecting to `https://` if someone uses `http://`
- are your certificates correctly set up and your production app works with `https://` protocol? (hint: this can't be testes in the spec tests really)
- something else?

SSL encryption should be transparent to your web app, are you having problems with that? Is your production app failing with HTTPS, and works properly with HTTP?
(Feel free to compose a new question when you give it some thought)

Answer (score 0):

#### Three ways to simulate HTTPS in request specs, with caveats:

1. If you're trying to simulate the behavior of your non-HTTPS app behind an HTTPS proxy, the easiest thing is to pass an HTTP header such as [`X-Forwarded-Proto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto):

   ```rb
   get :index, headers: { 'X-Forwarded-Proto' => 'https' }
   ```

   This will cause `request.base_url` to begin with `'https'`, `request.scheme` to return `'https'`, and `request.ssl?` to return `true`.

   However, under this approach you may still have issues with `Secure` cookies in request specs as `Rack::Test::Session` and `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session` will still use `http` URLs internally.
2. A workaround for that is is to instead set `env['rack.url_scheme']` to `https`:

   ```rb
   get :index, env: { 'rack.url_scheme' => 'https' }
   ```

   This will cause `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session#build_full_uri` to translate request paths to `https` URIs (while still not making any actual HTTP/HTTPS calls).

   A potential issue here, however, is that it only affects this specific request; in a complex setup with OmniAuth or other gems you may still end up with a mix of HTTP and HTTPS requests and more cookie issues.
3. What I finally settled on, myself, is to brute-force configure all integration-test requests to HTTPS. In `rails_helper.rb`:

   ```rb
   config.before(:example, type: :request) do
     integration_session.https!
   end
   ```

   This works for my tests, even with OmniAuth cookies in the mix, and it supports hard-coding `secure: true` and `cookies_same_site_protection = :none` in `application.rb`. It may have other negative side effects, though, that I just haven't run into.